# SQL: Guaranteeing exactly N rows matched for a many-to-many query?

Tags: sql, many-to-many

O. I have been trying to get this solved for two days now, no success, all my work is halted because of it.

Right to the point:

I have a many-to-many relation between these three tables:

```
Students
Students_Courses
Courses
```

I need to know exactly which students are enrolled in Physics AND Calculus AND CS101

They can be enrolled in other courses, but I need to know which ones are in those three courses.

```
SELECT * FROM Students A 
INNER JOIN Students_Courses B on A.id = B.student
INNER JOIN Courses C on B.course = C.id
WHERE C.name = Physics OR C.name = calculus OR C.name = cs101
```

BUT. This will return students in ANY of those courses.

If I change the WHERE clause to :

```
WHERE C.name = Physics AND C.name = calculus AND C.name = cs101
```

It won't return anything, because there is no such row which matches all three.

How do I do this? What is the SQL theory I'm missing here? I realize SQL works per-row, so I need per row filtering. But I am sure this is a common query I just can't find the name for the theory or what I'm missing here in order to solve it.

I did solve it by selecting ALL those courses and then filtering which students matched all three, but this was in the application, I wish this could be a single SQL query.

Thanks so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Good ideas here: http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html
http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/06/tagsystems-performance-tests.html

Comment: The SQL concept you are missing is [relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT student
FROM Students
WHERE student IN (SELECT student FROM Students_Courses B INNER JOIN Courses C on B.course = C.id WHERE C.name = Physics) AND
student IN (SELECT student FROM Students_Courses B INNER JOIN Courses C on B.course = C.id WHERE C.name = calculus) AND
student IN (SELECT student FROM Students_Courses B INNER JOIN Courses C on B.course = C.id WHERE C.name = cs101);
```

Comment: I had posted a thank you note but it didn't  show up. I was trying to do it without subqueries, but from your example I was able to gain the theory behind it: some how I must multiply the single query in to multiple lines, right? With subqueries you are achieving that. Sorry if the terms are confusing, I'm not a SQL expert and indeed this problem has beat me for the past work sessions. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 4):

mitch's solution will work better, but here's another take for fun.

```
SELECT A.id FROM Students A 
INNER JOIN Students_Courses B on A.id = B.student
INNER JOIN Courses C on B.course = C.id
WHERE C.name = Physics OR C.name = calculus OR C.name = cs101
GROUP BY A.id
HAVING count(DISTINCT C.id) = 3
```

Comment: Interesting take. We've filtered to one of those three courses,  then required it to have a precise count of 3. I can substitute this number for any number of required courses then... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do AND logic in a join, I typically just join the table in question multiple times.

```
SELECT * FROM Students A 
INNER JOIN Students_Courses B on A.id = B.student
INNER JOIN Courses C1 on B.course = C1.id
INNER JOIN Courses C2 on B.course = C2.id
INNER JOIN Courses C3 on B.course = C3.id
WHERE C1.name = Physics AND C2.name = calculus AND C3.name = cs101
```

I can't say for sure this is the most efficient way, but it makes sense when you think about it from the row-centric perspective.  If each "INNER JOIN" clause is capable of getting one row from the "leaf" table of the relationship, then it will take three "INNER JOIN" clauses to get three rows so that you can apply the AND logic to them.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, this is an elegant solution from my perspective! Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be with a set operator query.  Which I'd use depends on whether a student can be enrolled in multiple sections of the same course, and whether I want the duplicates to appear.  With multiple joins, you can theoretically return many copies of a student.  If I want each student to appear once, then I'd use the set operator:

```
SELECT A.STUDENTID 
FROM Students A  
INNER JOIN Students_Courses B 
    on A.id = B.student 
INNER JOIN Courses C1 
    on B.course = C1.id 
WHERE C1.name = 'Physics'
INTERSECT
SELECT A.STUDENTID 
FROM Students A  
INNER JOIN Students_Courses B 
    on A.id = B.student 
INNER JOIN Courses C2 
    on B.course = C2.id 
WHERE C2.name = 'calculus'
INTERSECT
SELECT A.STUDENTID 
FROM Students A  
INNER JOIN Students_Courses B 
    on A.id = B.student 
INNER JOIN Courses C3 
    on B.course = C3.id 
WHERE C3.name = 'cs101'
```

**EDIT**
Another way would be to use aggregation:

```
SELECT A.STUDENTID 
    , COUNT(distinct c3.name)
FROM Students A  
INNER JOIN Students_Courses B 
    on A.id = B.student 
INNER JOIN Courses C3 
    on B.course = C3.id 
WHERE C3.name IN 
    (   'cs101' 
        , 'calculus'
        , 'Pysics'
    )
GROUP BY a.studentid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c3.name) = 3
```

Both of these return student data exactly once for all students with at least one section of all three courses.  If a student can't be in more than one course of each name, then it will return the same as the multiple joins version above.  If he can, then a student in 2 physics courses, 2 calculus courses, and 3 cs101 courses would return 12 rows using multiple joins.